# fpdf alignment of cells

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF using `fpdf` and I'm having a small problem

I need to have 2 cells, like the following:

```
-------------------------  -------------------------
|  Address Line 1          |       Version         |
|  Address Line 2          |         1.0           |
|  City                    |       06/05/2011      | 
-------------------------  -------------------------
```

I've tried using `MultiCell()` but with no luck.

```
$address = '
    Address Line 1
    Address Line 2
    City
    Postcode';
$pdf->MultiCell(133.5, 2.7, $address, 'L', 'L');

$version = '
    Version 
    1.0
    06/05/2011';
$pdf->MultiCell(53.5, 2.7, $version, 'R', 'R');
```

I thought that I could possibly set the 'float' as it was left or right, which is what the docs say, but this doesn't seem to work. It just lists the Version multicell below the address and not to the right of it.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm:

Just use:

```
$pdf->Cell(width, height, text, border, position-next-cell, alignment);
```

So this means, to add a column afterwards 'position-next-cell' should be `0` what you're looking for is probably:

```
$pdf->Cell(133.5, 2.7, $address, 0, 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(53.5, 2.7, $version, 0, 1, 'L');
```

After the 2nd call you noticed the `1` which means a next cell is being placed underneath and not after (which the `0` would do.)