# Avoiding duplicates in fpdf cells

Tags: php, alignment, cell, fpdf

here is a screenshot which can explain you more clearly about how my everysecond cell is duplicating with the first one [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i207Z.png)I am new to PHP and I was trying to make a pdf from fpdf but the difficulty is that I wanted to align two cell beside each other, but cells are duplicating beside each other.
Here's my code:

```
require("library/fpdf/fpdf.php");
  class pdf extends fpdf {

        enter code here

       function Footer() {

        enter code here

    //Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        //Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        //Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

         }
     }
      $ctr=0;
     $pdf = new pdf('P','mm','A4');
     $pdf->AliasNbPages();
     $pdf->AddPage();
     $pdf->SetMargins(10,10,10);
     $pdf->SetXY(5,5);

                while ($lbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
          {
                    $ctr++;
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);{
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["hotelname"],1,0,'L');}
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);{
                    $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["hotelname"],1,1,'L');}
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);{
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Haji No-".$lbl["hajino"]."Ctr-"." ".$ctr,1,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Haji No-".$lbl["hajino"]."Ctr-"." ".$ctr,1,1,'L');
                    }
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["suffix"]." ". $lbl["surname"]." ". $lbl["name"]." ". $lbl["midname"],1,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["suffix"]." ". $lbl["surname"]." ". $lbl["name"]." ". $lbl["midname"],1,1,'L');

                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);{
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Room No - ". $lbl["roomno"]." "." "." "." "." "." "." ". "Bus No- ".$lbl["busname"],1,0,'L');
                    $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Room No - ". $lbl["roomno"]." "." "." "." "." "." "." ". "Bus No- ".$lbl["busname"],1,1,'L');
                    $pdf->Ln(10);
                    }




              }

            $pdf->Output('Hotel_label.pdf','D');


      } // Submit Tag Close

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by align and duplicating..it's not clear to me what you want to achieve..?? also [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911891/fpdf-alignment-of-cells) if it helps..

Comment: thanks for your reply but as u can see i had align it but when da query is fired that time the second cell gets repeated with the first one

Comment: how can i attach a pdf file??? it can explain u much better

Comment: i hav attached a scrrenshot of my pdf hope dt it can explain it to u

Comment: you can see the "hajino " in the screenshot which shows u that the cell data is duplicating n pls help me to print the next serial means
117 beside 116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try the below modified version of your code..

```
require("library/fpdf/fpdf.php");
  class pdf extends fpdf {
       // enter code here

       function Footer() {
       // enter code here

    //Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        //Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        //Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

         }
     }
      $ctr=0;

      $yheight=5;  //assign value for y-axis

     $pdf = new pdf('P','mm','A4');
     $pdf->AliasNbPages();
     $pdf->AddPage();
     $pdf->SetMargins(10,10,10);
     $pdf->SetXY(10,$yheight);


$loopvariable=1; //to check page break

$side=0;//to check left or right record placement

                while ($lbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
          {
                    $ctr++;
                    if($side==0){                   
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);{
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["hotelname"],1,1,'L');         
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Haji No-".$lbl["hajino"]."Ctr1-"." ".$ctr,1,1,'L');            
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["suffix"]." ". $lbl["surname"]." ". $lbl["name"]." ". $lbl["midname"],1,1,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Room No - ". $lbl["roomno"]." "." "." "." "." "." "." ". "Bus No- ".$lbl["busname"],1,1,'L');
            $pdf->Ln(10);
                     }

                    $side++;

                    }else{



                         $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);{
                              $pdf->SetXY(100,$yheight);
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["hotelname"],1,1,'L');  
                              $pdf->SetXY(100,$yheight+6);
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Haji No-".$lbl["hajino"]."Ctr2-"." ".$ctr,1,1,'L');
                         $pdf->SetXY(100,$yheight+12);
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,$lbl["suffix"]." ". $lbl["surname"]." ". $lbl["name"]." ". $lbl["midname"],1,1,'L');
             $pdf->SetXY(100,$yheight+18);
            $pdf->Cell(85,6,"Room No - ". $lbl["roomno"]." "." "." "." "." "." "." ". "Bus No- ".$lbl["busname"],1,1,'L');
            $pdf->Ln(10);
                    }
                    $side--;        
                    $yheight+=34;
                if($loopvariable%16==0){$yheight=10;}//reset the y-axis value after every 16 records i.e. after every page break

                    }


$loopvariable++;

              }

            $pdf->Output('Hotel_label.pdf','D');



      } // Submit Tag Close

    }
```